# How to start Tor on Ubuntu Touch OTA-15 (Libertine Container)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tor, libertine

I am trying to make may *Volla Phone* Tor-only (all traffic goes through Tor).
I created a container in Libertine and I am connected to my phone through SSH.

I installed Tor:
`libertine-container-manager exec -i xenial -c "apt install tor"`

Checked if it's installed:
`libertine-container-manager exec -i xenial -c "tor --version"`

*Output: `Tor version 0.2.9.14.`*

Tried to start Tor:
`libertine-container-manager exec -i xenial -c "service tor start"`

*Output: `/usr/bin/env.fakechroot: 135: /usr/bin/env.fakechroot: /etc/init.d/tor: not found`*

I am not able to get it running. `ss -nlt` doesn't show Tor running. Does anyone have an idea how to get it running or if there is another way to make this phone "Tor-only"? On my laptop [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/install-tor-proxy-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux) works perfectly, so I try something similar for my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Note 1:

Installing and running Tor within a libertine container will only route traffic from inside that container, and no traffic from any app running outside it.

At this point there's no good way to route all traffic to a tor node while using only Ubuntu touch.

Solution:

If you want route all your traffic through the Tor network, you should setup a server with Tor and OpenVPN server, and use that VPN from your Ubuntu Touch device.

Note 2:

Running daemons/servers that where not created to be used on smartphones is/will be mostly likely and often a really bad experience more often then not. Smartphone OS try to suspend processes in ways that these daemons/servers don't support, and will likely cause crashes and problems which can even cause serious security and safety.

Why is it a security issue?

Crashes are usually a good way to figure out ways to make a program access memory that it shouldn't be able to access and/or get privilege escalation.

Why is it a safety issue?

In case the user thinks it's doing something for which tor is helping protecting him/her, but because it crashed, it's not running, therefore not protecting the user as him/her things it's.

Note 3:

If you just want to route your browser traffic through Tor, than you should look at [OnionSurf](https://open-store.io/app/onion-surf.collaproductions), it's not a privacy centric browser like the Tor Browser but will send your taffic through the Tor Network